# Store template in module

Tags: 8, theming

I want to store a template for my content-type in a module. This module provides the content-type (via features). My template *"node--my-content-type.html.twig"* should be in this module, too. Not in the Themes templates/ folder.

I know there are some related questions yet. I think I got the first step already; Drupal is recognizing my template and is outputing its contents.

In Drupal 7 the approach was made with something like this:

```
function mymodule_theme($existing, $type, $theme, $path) {
  return array(
  'node__my_content_type_machine_name' => array(
      'render element' => 'elements',
      'template' => 'templates/node--my-content-typee-machine-name',
    )
  );
}
```

Drupal 8 recognizes the template when I change this a bit.

```
'template' => 'node--my-content-type-machine-name'
```

So far so good. But now I am trying to render a field in my template and here I am failing.

```
{{ content.field_body }} ==> This is doing **nothing**
```

In my theme´s template-folder this is working fine. Any ideas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are missing the base hook definition. See how [system_theme()](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21modules%21system%21system.module/function/system_theme/8) does it for block templates. So, add `'base hook' => 'node'` and it should work.