# Custom Twig Template for Custom Content Type

Tags: 8

In my custom modules I am creating a custom content type. I also need to apply a twig template for this custom content type, but I can't seem to get it to actually apply.

in myModule.module file I have:

```
function myModule_theme($existing, $type, $theme, $path) {


return [
    'faculty_bio_node' => [
      'variables' => [],
    ]
  ];
}
```

and I have a custom twig template named :   faculty_bio-node.html.twig

The content types machine name is faculty_bio

Comment: You don't need a theme hook to be able to use a custom template for a content type. That's built in to Drupal's theming already. Name your template node--faculty-bio.html.twig for example. https://www.drupal.org/docs/8/theming/twig/twig-template-naming-conventions

Comment: I have the twig template inside a templates folder, and the naming convention you shared did not work (with a cache clear of course)   Any idea what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: If the template is in your module folder rather than the theme, then yes, that won't work. You'll need to implement the hook https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core!lib!Drupal!Core!Render!theme.api.php/function/hook_theme_suggestions_HOOK_alter/8.2.x I think, though there may be other ways to override the location of a template.

Comment: Use the steps in https://www.drupal.org/docs/8/theming/twig/debugging-twig-templates to turn on debugging, and look at the page source. Can you find the list with template suggestions and see if it contains `node--faculty-bio.html.twig`? (Also, try putting the template file into the site's theme, just to make sure it's not some weird problem with the module...)

Comment: well putting the template file into the sites theme successfully loaded the twig template, however, I'm still unable to get the twig template to load from my custom module.   There's got to be a way to make it work...

Comment: If you want to load the template from the module folder you are in the right hook, but you need to use the correct base hook. This means you have to start the template name with the base hook and a double underscore `node__` and declare the base hook in theme_hook(), see https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/194498/store-template-in-module

Comment: AHA!    That did it for me!  Thank you @4k4   If you want to put that in as an answer I'll happily accept it~!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you want to load the template from the module folder you are in the right hook, but you need to use the correct base hook. This means you have to start the template name with the base hook and a double underscore `node__` and declare the base hook in theme_hook(), see [Store template in module](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/194498/store-template-in-module).

hook_theme():

```
function myModule_theme($existing, $type, $theme, $path) {


return [
    'node__faculty_bio' => [
      'base hook' => 'node',
    ]
  ];
}
```

The Twig template path and name would then be `mymodule/templates/node--faculty-bio.html.twig`.

Comment: been strugling with this for hours, awesome man thans

Answer (score 0):

Drupal won't recognize the template using an underscore.
Rather than using:
**faculty_bio-node.html.twig** 
Can you try
**faculty-bio-node.html.twig**

Using this you can leave the return method for what it is.