# Custom Twig template for confirmation webform page being cached too hard

Tags: 8, theming, webforms

I've created a custom module which does some additional form handling and styling required for my project - this is all working fine.

Due to the size of the form - 50 odd fields - I'm setting up a Twig file in my module for the confirmation screen as it is far easier to manage it in my IDE than using the GUI. My confirmation page lists all the values styled in a specific way and laid out in a specific way. I've technically got it working by using `hook_theme_suggestions_webform_confirmation_alter` and `hook_theme` to point to my Twig template.

However, I've just recently discovered that, due to Drupal 8 internal page caching being so aggressive for anonymous users, the confirmation page is getting cached for everyone regardless of the actual submission values. So the first user gets it fine but the second submission from then on gets the cached version from the first.

I've read in other places to make use of `hook_preprocess_webform_confirmation` and set `$variables['message']['#cache']['max-age'] = 0;`. However, this is never called which I suspect is due to how I went about using my Twig template mentioned above.

Can someone help point me in the right direction here. Am I supposed to setup some kind of overwriting route in order to change the theme file or is it just a matter of tweaking what I've already done?

Functions in my `.module` file

```
function application_theme($existing, $type, $theme, $path) {
  $info = [
    'gib_application' => [
      'render element' => 'form',
      'template' => 'application-form'
    ],
    'application_form_confirmation' => [
      'template' => 'application-form-confirmation'
    ]
  ];
  return $info;
}
```

And

```
function application_theme_suggestions_webform_confirmation_alter(array &$suggestions, array $variables) {
  if (empty($variables['header'])) {
    $suggestions[] = 'application_form_confirmation';
  }
}
```

**UPDATE**

I've tweaked my `hook_theme` function to the below and also disabled `hook_theme_suggestions_webform_confirmation_alter` assuming it isn't relevant so long as `hook_theme` is defining the correct name.

```
function application_theme($existing, $type, $theme, $path) {
  $info = [
    'gib_application' => [
      'render element' => 'form',
      'template' => 'application-form'
    ],
    'webform_confirmation__application_form' => [
      'template' => 'application-form-confirmation',
      'base hook' => 'webform_confirmation'
    ],
  ];
  return $info;
}
```

Here are the Twig suggestions:

```
<!-- FILE NAME SUGGESTIONS:
   * webform-confirmation--application-form.html.twig
   x webform-confirmation.html.twig
-->
```

Unfortunately now my Twig template isn't being loaded at all now (due to dropping `hook_theme_suggestions_webform_confirmation_alter`.

Comment: Seems like `$variables['message']` is wrong. Please retry it with `$variables['#cache']['max-age'] = 0;`.

Comment: But probably `['#cache']['contexts'][] = 'user'` or  `['#cache']['contexts'][] = 'user.id'` is more accurate. But I've not tested if `user` or `user.id` contexts exist at all. It's just a wild guess.

Comment: To clarify, the hook to allow me to use  $variables is never called. If I stop using the theme suggestion hook then I can alter the cache but this means I can't have a custom twig template

Comment: What happens when you ensure that your moduel's implementation of `hook_preprocess_webform_confirmation` runs last via [`hook_module_implements_alter`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21lib%21Drupal%21Core%21Extension%21module.api.php/function/hook_module_implements_alter/8.2.x)?

Comment: `hook_preprocess_webform_confirmation` isn't being invoked at all so I can't alter the order of how it is implemented. I assume how I've triggered my twig template has had a flow on affect to stop the normal processing of the webform module itself?

Comment: Could you maybe update your question and add your `hook_theme` and `hook_theme_suggestions...` code?

Comment: Have updated for you

Comment: You can add suggestions for existing templates or create custom templates. Suggestions start with the base hook and double underscores. For custom twig templates you have to create your own set of variables, which you can't use in preprocess hooks of existing theme hooks. So it's unclear what you are trying to do.

Comment: Thanks @4k4. I had tried to initially just add a different Twig template based on the the Twig debug suggestions but they never seem to get picked up by my module. If I add theme in to the theme templates directory they are picked up but never by my module which is why I then tried the code I've used above. Is there a way to ensure the template in my module are used as priority over the webform template files?

Comment: Yes, this is correct, to move the template to the module folder you have to implement hook_theme(), but the naming rules still apply, that the template needs to start with the base hook, in your case `webform_confirmation__` and instead of defining your own variables reference the base hook. Then the preprocess hook you are trying to invoke should work. See https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/267263/custom-twig-template-for-custom-content-type

Comment: I've updated my question with current code - still not working unfortunately. I've included Twig debug suggestions as well.

Comment: The `template` in theme_hook() is not necessary, but you need the suggestion. The linked example is different because there the suggestion for the content type already exists.

Comment: It's working! After removing the `template`, and then renaming my Twig filename accordingly, it is now loading the Twig template from my module while also allowing me to use `hook_preprocess_webform_confirmation` so that I can disable cache.Unfortunately the `preprocess` hook isn't called everytime for anonymous users which means I can't use it to disable cache! That is a different question though which I'll look into.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Summary of the final answer to my original questions.

`hook_theme` was still required in the module to state that it can be used for suggested Twig templates.

```
function application_theme($existing, $type, $theme, $path) {
  $info = [
    'webform_confirmation__application_form' => [
      'base hook' => 'webform_confirmation'
    ]
  ];
  return $info;
}
```

`hook_theme_suggestions_webform_confirmation_alter` was not required in the end once `hook_theme` was setup correctly.

`hook_theme` needed to have the suggested name as proposed by the Twig debugger. Twig suggested these files:

```
<!-- FILE NAME SUGGESTIONS:
   * webform-confirmation--application-form.html.twig
   x webform-confirmation.html.twig
-->
```

The dashes get converted to underscores i.e. `webform-confirmation--application-form` is translated to `webform_confirmation__application_form`.

The only variable associated with that part of the array was `base hook`. This states to use the initial hook functionality rather than setting it all up again in my module - [read more here](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21lib%21Drupal%21Core%21Render%21theme.api.php/function/hook_theme/8.6.x).

> **base hook**: Used for theme suggestions only: the base theme hook name.
>   Instead of this suggestion's implementation being used directly, the
>   base hook will be invoked with this implementation as its first
>   suggestion. The base hook's files will be included and the base hook's
>   preprocess functions will be called in addition to any suggestion's
>   preprocess functions. If an implementation of
>   hook_theme_suggestions_HOOK() (where HOOK is the base hook) changes
>   the suggestion order, a different suggestion may be used in place of
>   this suggestion. If after hook_theme_suggestions_HOOK() this
>   suggestion remains the first suggestion, then this suggestion's
>   function or template will be used to generate the rendered output.

`template` was not required so long as the filename of my Twig file matched the one Twig was suggesting. For my site it was `webform-confirmation--application-form.html.twig`.

With the above tweaks my Twig file was loading correctly while also still using all of the original hooks from the webform module.

The other issue was the confirmation page being cached for anonymous users. I was able to resolve this by using `\Drupal::service('page_cache_kill_switch')->trigger();` inside `hook_preprocess_webform_confirmation`. After clearing Drupal's cache the confirmation page would then never get cached again.

```
function application_preprocess_webform_confirmation(array &$variables) {
  \Drupal::service('page_cache_kill_switch')->trigger();
}
```

This same logic will apply for updating Twig templates in other modules as well - this is not a webform module only solution.

Thanks to [4k4](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/users/47547/4k4) and [Stefanos](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/users/57183/stefanos-petrakis) for the guidance.

Answer (score 4):

Seems like there are two different issues here:

(a) Loading a twig template from an arbitrary folder.

Could you try setting the `path` theme property and see if that allows your twig template to be loaded? For example:

```
'webform_confirmation__application_form' => [
  'template' => 'application-form-confirmation',
  'base hook' => 'webform_confirmation'
  'path' => \Drupal::moduleHandler()->getModule('application')->getPath() . '/templates',
],
```

(b) Modifying the cache settings for a part of your render variables.

You should check that the cache tags bubble all the way up from the `message` array. Apparently:

> You have to render the content variable to ensure that its cache tags
>   bubble up and end up in the page cache.

as mentioned here => (https://www.previousnext.com.au/blog/ensuring-drupal-8-block-cache-tags-bubble-up-page)

So, one place to start would be trying to render the whole `content` variable in your twig template, provided you got past (a)

Update: You could also try calling `\Drupal::service(''page_cache_kill_switch'')->trigger();` in order to avoid Internal Page Cache to interfere with the request and page loading.

A simple way to do this inside a twig template would be using an approach similar to this module => https://github.com/stefanospetrakis/twig_killswitch_trigger

Good luck!

P.S.: Sample code is also available here => https://www.drupal.org/sandbox/stefanospetrakis/3011610, I may promote this to a full project if there is any potential interest.

Comment: I have the twig template loading now thanks to comments under my question. Caching is still an issue though. I've checked the header tags and I can see cache tags there that appear to be unique to the form submission - this would tell me it should be unique? That said I only see this on my dev box and not on production which is where the issue is. Configuration is all the same except for a normal setup for a production install.

Comment: @SaRiD : Threw some code that you could use over here => https://github.com/stefanospetrakis/twig_killswitch_trigger . If you don't want to use that module, you can still try to call `\Drupal::service(''page_cache_kill_switch'')->trigger();` from your own implementation. Updated my answer as well.

Comment: Yep `page_cache_kill_switch` does the trick thanks! I was able to simply add it in to `hook_preprocess_webform_confirmation` - nice job quickly creating a reusable module though.

Comment: Perfect! Happy it worked out, great summarised answer below!

Answer (score 0):

You can add the following statement to your Twig template to turn off caching.

```
{{ {'#cache': {'max-age': 0}} }}
```